Canning question lid sound
Canning beans...lid popped down but the tapping sound is different then the rest of the jars. Unscrewed lid and picked it up. Lid on. Is it OK?

This is a bit confusing so its hard to answer. What kind of jars and lids are you using. You say you unscrewed the lid but then say the lid is on, are you saying you have mason jars with 2 piece lids and rings, and that you unscrewed the ring but the lid has stayed on?
